# Print inside lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently using syntax like this:

```
print(*list(map(lambda a: [something to do], input())))
```

It's working fine if the return type is a string but not for a number.

For example. The below script is for finding the square root of three in two different version

```
print(*list(map(lambda a: int(a)**(1/3), input())))
```

and

```
SQRT = lambda a: a**(1/3)
print(SQRT(int(input())))
```

When I input `9` both return `2.080083823051904` (Which is correct) but when I input `10` the first one return `1.0 0.0` and `2.154434690031884` for the second one.

I wanted to know that is there any way I can print directly from lambda that returns a number without causing a problem addressed above?

Comment: This is not a printing issue...

Comment: Note that the `list(..)` call is redundant, straight up `print(*map(...))` would have the same result without building an intermediary list object first. That's because `*` takes any iterable, not just sequences.

Comment: `stuff ** (1/3)` is not a square root...

Comment: When you map over a string, you map over each character. So `map(f, "10")` is essentially the same as `[f("1"), f("0")]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are focusing on the wrong issue here. This is not a problem with printing; removing the `print()` function from the equation will give you the same results.

You are iterating over the **individual characters** of the input string, producing the cube root of `1` and `0` respectively when entering `'10'` into the input prompt, or of `9` when you enter `'9'`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda a: int(a)**(1/3), '10'))
[1.0, 0.0]  # [1 ** (1/3), 0 ** (1/3)]
>>> list(map(lambda a: int(a)**(1/3), '9'))
[2.080083823051904]  # [9 ** (1/3)]
```

`input()` returns a string object, and strings are iterables; a sequence of the individual characters. For `'10'` iteration gives you `'1'` and `'0'`:

```
>>> list('10')  # just iteration, pulling out the separate parts
['1', '0']
```

Your second code snippets applies `int()` to the *whole* `input()` string, so then you get the square root of `10` and `9`:

```
>>> SQRT(int('10'))
2.154434690031884
>>> SQRT(int('9'))
2.080083823051904
```

If you wanted the cube root of the input, *don't use `map()`*:

```
>>> CBRT = lambda a: a ** (1/3)
>>> CBRT(int('10'))
>>> CBRT(int('10'))
2.154434690031884
```

Side note: `*` works on any iterable, including the iterator object that `map()` produces, so `print(*map(...))` works just as well as `print(*list(map(...)))`, but without creating a list object first that then is discarded again.

Answer (score 1):

By using `map` on the returning string of `input()`, you are treating the string as a sequence of individual characters, and hence the cube root of 1 and 0 when you input `'10'`.

You should use the second method you posted, since the all the `lambda`, `map`, and unpacking add no value to the problem you're solving.